# WindowsFabricAdministrator group is missing on Windows Server 2012

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, windows-server-2012-r2, app-fabric

AppFabric Service is not running on my server. To resolve this issue, somewhere I found that client account should be part of following groups:

```
WindowsFabricAdministrators
WindowsFabricAllowedUsers
WinRMReoteWMIUsers_
```

But I don't see this groups in my server. Can anyone help me to bring it?

Comment: did you install the pre-req of SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)
and execute in console:

```
Cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform installer" 
WebpiCmd.exe /Install /products:WindowsFabric
```

This groups will be created during this process.